# Car keeps breaking fuel injectors?

Tags: engine, fuel-system, bmw, electronic-control-module, fuel-injectors

Ok so i'm having quiet a strange issues with one of my cars (08 X5 E70 4.8L V8) that may be worth discussing. It seems to keep "blowing" through injectors on only one bank.

Suddenly i noticed CEL and a code: "O2 sensors interchanged", but since nobody touched anything around the sensors i investigated further, car started misfiring, replaced all spark plugs, coils, still kept doing it, a short in the system caused some more O2 sensor codes to be thrown, fixed the short, codes went away except the "sensors interchanged" one.

Checked the injectors all four on bank 2 were faulty, they were not spraying but *pouring fuel*, no physical damage, the car is getting about 5.5mpg maybe worse, the cat on bank 2 seems to have started to turn black from un-burnt fuel, there was a combination of black smoke and if the car kept idling white smoke, car chokes up, misfires, shakes and stumbles, no codes except the O2 code.

Replaced the injectors, drove it 30 minutes worked great and then all issues came back, now on the same bank, 2 of the injectors are doing the same thing, i didn't drive it much in this condition so i'm unsure if the rest of them would go too. What could be causing this? Would a faulty ECU cause this, for it's probable that the ECU could be faulty in my car.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Could "dirt" be fouling the injectors ? There must a be a filter someplace to change.